# how to update the names inside the tags of xml using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tring to change the value of the name inside parent tag whenever there are Z- in the last of the name. by taking the value from my table , let say there are only three such pattern where name ends with Z- and I have values to update in list val.

how can I do that?

lets say this is my XML,

```
<parent name="A-6/Z-9/B-64/Z-12">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="A1/Zh/B/C-12">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="AS-5/ZD-9/B-67/Z-13">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="An4/Zd-8/B-5/C-13">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="A-76/Z-8/B-56/Z-14">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="A-45/Z-ty/B-9/C-14">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A">
<p name ="B">
</list>
</item>
</parent>
```

this is my values in list val = `["Z-99","Z-98","Z-97"]`

I want to fix these values in my XML as whenever parent have name ends with Z for example
these

```
<parent name="A-6/Z-9/B-64/Z-12">
<parent name="AS-5/ZD-9/B-67/Z-13">
<parent name="A-76/Z-8/B-56/Z-14">
```

I want this

```
<parent name="A-6/Z-9/B-64/Z-99">
<parent name="AS-5/ZD-9/B-67/Z-98">
<parent name="A-76/Z-8/B-56/Z-97">
```

I tried these but nothing is working for me

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Z]+-+[0-9]+/+Z+-+[0-9]$')
for i in soup.find_all('parent', distName=pattern):
       for j in val:
           i.string = i.string[:-2]+str(j)


 for i, val in zip(soup.select('parent > name^="Z-"')
         i.string = i.string[:-2]+str(val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script to change all required `name=` attributes from `<parent>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<parent name="A-6/Z-9/B-64/Z-12">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>

<parent name="A1/Zh/B/C-12">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>

<parent name="AS-5/ZD-9/B-67/Z-13">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>

<parent name="An4/Zd-8/B-5/C-13">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>

<parent name="A-76/Z-8/B-56/Z-14">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>
<parent name="A-45/Z-ty/B-9/C-14">
<item>
<list>
<p name="A"></p>
<p name="B"></p>
</list>
</item>
</parent>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

values = ["Z-99","Z-98","Z-97"]

r = re.compile(r'Z-\d+$')
for parent, new_val in zip(soup.find_all('parent', {'name': r}), values):
    parent['name'] = r.sub(new_val, parent['name'])

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<parent name="A-6/Z-9/B-64/Z-99">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
<parent name="A1/Zh/B/C-12">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
<parent name="AS-5/ZD-9/B-67/Z-98">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
<parent name="An4/Zd-8/B-5/C-13">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
<parent name="A-76/Z-8/B-56/Z-97">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
<parent name="A-45/Z-ty/B-9/C-14">
 <item>
  <list>
   <p name="A">
   </p>
   <p name="B">
   </p>
  </list>
 </item>
</parent>
```